# Zendesk chat combined pem uploaded but not receive push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, zendesk

I followed this document:

https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios-chat-sdk/push_notifications

And combined Cert PEM and Key PEM.

I used `openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert Certificates.pem -key PrivateKey.pem`

> openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert
>   Certificates.pem -key PrivateKey.pem
>
> CONNECTED(00000007) depth=1 C = US, O = "Entrust, Inc.", OU = See
>   www.entrust.net/legal-terms, OU = "(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for
>   authorized use only", CN = Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
>   verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify
>   return:0
>   --- Certificate chain  0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com    i:/C=US/O=Entrust,
>   Inc./OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms/OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. -
>   for authorized use only/CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K  1
>   s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms/OU=(c) 2012
>   Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only/CN=Entrust Certification
>   Authority - L1K    i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048
>   incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net
>   Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
>   --- Server certificate
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIHSDCCBjCgAwIBAgIQWxjih7/N45IAAAAAUOIMDDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
>   ujELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUVudHJ1c3QsIEluYy4xKDAmBgNVBAsT
>   H1NlZSB3d3cuZW50cnVzdC5uZXQvbGVnYWwtdGVybXMxOTA3BgNVBAsTMChjKSAy
>   MDEyIEVudHJ1c3QsIEluYy4gLSBmb3IgYXV0aG9yaXplZCB1c2Ugb25seTEuMCwG
>   A1UEAxMlRW50cnVzdCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eSAtIEwxSzAeFw0x
>   ODA0MjQwMjUyNTNaFw0yMDA0MjAwMzIyNTJaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYD
>   VQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRIwEAYDVQQHEwlDdXBlcnRpbm8xEzARBgNVBAoTCkFw
>   cGxlIEluYy4xJzAlBgNVBAMTHmdhdGV3YXkuc2FuZGJveC5wdXNoLmFwcGxlLmNv
>   bTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALGgtoDaNuLjk9KpFkLp
>   xK1RhWdXMkGJlZeut40b4DabOUNsgmL9w0pGvFRa4u79Lzn8mDLQ06u71Ko5oVwV
>   da1VyI6+QX2naiTbAKVYB9qCdDim/TmXvnQUzhA5E4qXwmJlJd1QDCsV5kiy0SXJ
>   YNNXe/TAtO66t+zzT6WO9cVgqkeiEHq71khG5y4ST7E3uuPrlfHc/fcepneGNFnk
>   Y00ENxsTqPffvuTadKRXTdH3XKEUznrSCmi7wLQVAy3jvOJQ8q/tkuKl3ESbPZuW
>   qHHHN4VQFY+p9zdhGrmucIC7BvaEkZeDAvyYUCnJ8dtxLaCumR47esrEA3/p6YTN
>   Tn0CAwEAAaOCA40wggOJMCkGA1UdEQQiMCCCHmdhdGV3YXkuc2FuZGJveC5wdXNo
>   LmFwcGxlLmNvbTCCAfQGCisGAQQB1nkCBAIEggHkBIIB4AHeAHUAVYHUwhaQNgFK
>   6gubVzxT8MDkOHhwJQgXL6OqHQcT0wwAAAFi9aztYAAABAMARjBEAiBJbsuBQS+U
>   zNNArriSL0K9eKpZgmsQzvNlNxDqAZFLdwIgS61d6HuV9+UOkZ30HajpgL0raI+m
>   EvRyLAK6dzfIy+sAdwDd6x0reg1PpiCLga2BaHB+Lo6dAdVciI09EcTNtuy+zAAA
>   AWL1rO1iAAAEAwBIMEYCIQDc6OHQPat4UNQ6z0pbM6s7YEXWCuO0LUfDTlHGmCbw
>   dwIhAN/qlMFUciYP2o1gTKD9LtBc8hFQ1c35n4c7L2Cw47cuAHUAu9nfvB+KcbWT
>   lCOXqpJ7RzhXlQqrUugakJZkNo4e0YUAAAFi9aztgwAABAMARjBEAiBgEzNNxFKL
>   FS/9Ix29xIjpGZd2lXNz31iwdQl5eTwfggIgBKe3Hqk0KTn0aaTWu8y7+3ZzSv0I
>   svstJ/uaLlTbeUkAdQCkuQmQtBhYFIe7E6LMZ3AKPDWYBPkb37jjd80OyA3cEAAA
>   AWL1rO2HAAAEAwBGMEQCIGUEnyBQyHZ/JaJ9LRQqqQ0h2Ez9fzqhIaHk6nO4lYnf
>   AiBeuRikWxw8yuYkXd+n0i97cagfVDoi1AHRitCvk8zUmTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMC
>   BaAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMDMGA1UdHwQsMCowKKAm
>   oCSGImh0dHA6Ly9jcmwuZW50cnVzdC5uZXQvbGV2ZWwxay5jcmwwSwYDVR0gBEQw
>   QjA2BgpghkgBhvpsCgEFMCgwJgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWGmh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZW50cnVz
>   dC5uZXQvcnBhMAgGBmeBDAECAjBoBggrBgEFBQcBAQRcMFowIwYIKwYBBQUHMAGG
>   F2h0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmVudHJ1c3QubmV0MDMGCCsGAQUFBzAChidodHRwOi8vYWlh
>   LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L2wxay1jaGFpbjI1Ni5jZXIwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUgqJwdN28
>   Uz/Pe9T3zX+nYMYKTL8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFER7zAX8nlMJjpQL8PV9MYeeWpMOMAkG
>   A1UdEwQCMAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAJGeRI1Wht6YTfvdz2wKmZS8TFpX
>   gBRUUUNFFG0ihXuK48XKkKJviKikWl+qvExZqQN44aaIB5CHDgwUL6udQDZg7E27
>   rdC72tL79zHWbt/ukm6ffGa9SIIwtcJh+apfSA2YI5cmS9Da5v12VTkKizumgGVQ
>   pxP3EPnriAaj93BLVou5IUmuXOAbFqB2ZfhaX3kyiB+Hj87DGIU6qW8LnmKL22xi
>   77ksB4zbOm3FK71xwEOpakcC7rLbivRuB1iBV2TggXWvPf5snTV3jRTi8Cmqam4A
>   S+74TbYXfUQHBWIRQMktF+I/N9camXrf9ZfFTPzCO9GD6hbl6ae//zWDhh0=
>   -----END CERTIFICATE----- subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple
>   Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust,
>   Inc./OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms/OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. -
>   for authorized use only/CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
>   --- Acceptable client certificate CA names /C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Root CA /C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple
>   Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations
>   Certification Authority /CN=Apple Application Integration 2
>   Certification Authority/OU=Apple Certification Authority/O=Apple
>   Inc./C=US /C=US/ST=CA/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=Internet Software
>   and Services/CN=iCloud Test/emailAddress=APNS-Dev@group.apple.com
>   /C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple
>   Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com /C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple
>   Certification Authority/CN=Apple Application Integration Certification
>   Authority
>   --- SSL handshake has read 4165 bytes and written 2411 bytes
>   --- New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE Expansion:
>   NONE No ALPN negotiated SSL-Session:
>       Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>       Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
>       Session-ID:
>       Session-ID-ctx:
>       Master-Key: 947F3D735AEEFB1633D0E18CD8CAFF5F6AB789DC518AEED4913382554437C2EE686F50A9267B285E798AB40FAEC389FD
>       Start Time: 1552990882
>       Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
>
> ### Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Then I upload to Zendesk Dashboard successfully. But after that I can not receive push notification.

Comment: I also could not receive push notifications, but it seems that zendesk wont use the sandbox for push notifications so you cant receive push notifications without doing an ad hoc build, which makes it an absolute pain to debug if you have problems

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: I have the exact same problem but with distribution push notifications. 
Zendesk has a sandbox checkbox now, I clicked it and got my sandbox app working just fine, but when I build an adhoc version in Release mode the notifications don't arrive to my device. I've certified that the checkbox was off upon production testing, the certificate used is production, the aps-environment is set to production..

I also tested against apple's APNs gateway and got the 0 (ok) status as well using the command below
    openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert mycert.pem -key mycert.pem